# logging SQL expressions from within HSQLDB

Tags: logging, hsqldb

I use HSQLDB in my application. Now i need to log every single sql statement which was executed. I do not want to handle SQL-logging myself. Is there a standart way of doing this from within HSQLDB?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

HSQLDB 2.2.x supports SQL logging. Suppose your database is named `test` and you connect using the JDBC URL `jdbc:hsqldb:file:test`

1. test.log is the data change log used internally by HSQLDB. It does not contain SELECT statements. It is created and deleted by HSQLDB. This is not what you are looking for.
2. test.sql.log is the log that contains all the SQL statements with time and session info, together with any arguments for prepared statements. This log is created if you use:

   SET DATABASE EVENT LOG SQL LEVEL 3

It contains entries such as these:

```
2012-02-08 22:19:36.484 DETAIL 4 CALL USER() 
2012-02-08 22:19:36.484 DETAIL 4 call database_version() 
2012-02-08 22:19:36.484 DETAIL 4 COMMIT 
2012-02-08 22:19:36.500 DETAIL 4 INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(0,'Laura','Steel','429 Seventh Av.','Dallas')
```

You can use the hsqldb.sqllog=3 on the URL, e.g. jdbc:hsqldb:file:test;hsqldb.sqllog=3

3. test.sql.app.log is the log that contains entries for internal persistence operations. This is not related to the executed SQL statements.

See the Guide here and check the command and property syntax at the end of the chapter:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_monitoring_operation

Comment: If my database is encrypted, is there a standart way to enable encryption of sql-log too?

Comment: No, but it is easy to modify the source for this. See the org.hsqldb.lib.SimpleLog class.

Comment: thanks a lot!! ``SET DATABASE EVENT LOG SQL LEVEL 3`` works like a charm!

Comment: after adding the property in connection url (`jdbc:hsqldb:mem:foo;hsqldb.sqllog=3;`) i finally get this SQL statement in my console output

Answer (score 1):

Not HSQLDB specific, but if your client is using JDBC perhaps easiest way to log SQL statements is to use JDBC driver wrapper. There are plenty [implementations](http://www.google.ca/search?q=jdbc%20spy) to choose from.

Comment: I'm considering this kind of solution, but my goal is to avoid introducing new libraies into my project.

Comment: OK. I used just to write aspects for JDBC Connection/Statement/PreparedStatement for similar purpose and wire them via Spring Interceptors if you're using Sprint. It's just a few classes and not that hard actually.

Comment: In fact this project is to big for me to understand everything. We use Spring but i have no experience in it. Spring-using code was written by someone else. And I have no time to learn now. We also useing Hibernate and Log4J. My closest guess how to solve my task is to turn SQL statement and parameters logging, then redirect this log to my destination file.

Comment: You never mentioned that you're using Hibernate. In this case you could set 'hibernate.show_sql' property to 'true' and it should print you SQL statements.

Comment: Using JDBC spy would be next easiest thing - all you have to do is to change definition of JDBC ConnectionPool (either in Spring context file or in your application server). See for example here: http://blog.frankel.ch/tag/p6spy

Comment: I didn't mentioned Hibernate because I wanted to figure out is there a little lower level solution. As I understand you propose SQL spy as  only method? No such functionality in HSQLDB itself?

Comment: SQL spy is most generic. HSQLDB also seems to have 'hsqldb.sqllog' property which if you set to '2' should give you SQL logging as described here: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html

Comment: I'm not sure what this option for. Tried to use it.Log file being created, but deleted on server shutdown. Searching for option to leave log file and possibly append to it on next start.

Comment: OK, i'm officialy confused. I see that **.log** file is written regardless of option **hsqldb.sqllog=2**. And i've found no **.sql.log** file near database. Since **.log** is deleted on shutdown i think i missed something important.

Comment: How are you specifying property? Anyhow, I think I answered your original question of how to log SQL from HSQLDB. ;)

Comment: Well, you almost did. fredt mentioned that sqllog feature exists in hsqldb since version 2.2. No wonder i can't see any log: i use version 2.0 now. Thanks anyway. You helped a lot too.