# Checking versions of read set at commit in JPA 2 with optimistic locking

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink, hsqldb, optimistic-locking

I'm using optimistic locking in a JPA2 (using EclipseLink v2.4) application (no container, just JavaSE).  I'm trying to implement strong consistency, so I want the versions of all objects read during a transaction to be checked at commit.

When I use MySQL as the target DB, things happen as I expect: when I have a client performing read-only transactions concurrent with a client performing writes, some of the read-only transactions abort (and are retried).

However, when I use HSQLDB (v2.2.9), the read-only transactions never abort.  In fact, tcpdump shows nothing going across the wire at all!

What's going on here? I've tried playing around with the isolation level to no avail.  I don't see why that would matter anyway -- it seems like EclipseLink should be generating the roughly same SQL regardless of isolation.  Maybe some weird optimization is going on?

Reading the JPA spec is confusing.  Am I even guaranteed that my read set versions will be checked, or only the versions of objects that are modified or deleted?

Comment: Why don't you provide us a bit of your code?

Comment: The code is a JPA version of the [OO7 database benchmark](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dewitt/includes/benchmarking/oo7.pdf).  It is supposed to model a CAD application.  The transactions traverse a tree-structured graph of 'Assemblies' with leaves of parts.  The read-only transactions only read the parts, while the write transactions modify fields of the parts.

Answer (score 1):

Isolation level could explain why some things work in MySql (e.g if set to Serializable), but as you said, optimistic locking does not need that (but as said, may be it is not the optimistic locking that works in MySql).

I would try to upgrade/downgrade the HSQLDB version for a quick check that it is not a BUG there.

Also I suppose that you checked that you entities have fields annotated with `@Version` and that you lock **EXPLICITLY** the entities (by passing a `LockModeType` when you call EntityManager.find(), refresh() or lock()), as it is not clear if/which is the default `LockModeType` ([check this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568475/jpa-and-default-locking-mode)).

Also, if you want to debug a bit more, you could look what queries are sent to HSQL (take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192815/logging-sql-expressions-from-within-hsqldb) and [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html) too see how to log the queries). Specifically I would check how the `@Version`-annotated fields are updated/checked. Of course with the debugger attached.

Of course, without the code it is not so easy to say what could be the problems, but I suppose it is a problem in code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I have looked at the SQL sent to HSQL and it only appears to be generating "UPDATE X SET Y=Z WHERE VERSION = W" type queries.  That is to say, it only generates SQL for objects being updated.  You are correct: I am using @Version for the version field of each object.

Comment: I added some comments regarding LockModeType: do you explicitly lock the entities?

Comment: I don't explicitly lock the entities in either case.  I've seen the SO question you referenced, but I don't see how that would cause the MySQL configuration to generate version checks while skipping them for HSQL.  I am beginning to wonder whether explicitly locking the entities is required, though. In which case, ugh, what a terrible abstraction.

Comment: When you say that in MySQL version is checked, I understand that OptimisticLockExceptions are eventually thrown. The JPA specification simply does not say what is the default lock type, and if you want ANY locking, then it is your duty to specify one. On the other side, I have read that EclipseLink takes the LockModeType.Optimistic by default. So simply try specifying a LockingModeType and tell us the result :)

Comment: Unfortunately, explicitly locking the entities was something I was trying to avoid.  It means I need to have a reference to the entitymanager basically throughout the entire program.  I'm still confused about why the behavior differs between DBs, but thanks for your help!

Comment: I understand that, but for the sake of completeness: could you try to lock them explicitly? Also, if you simply want to get rid of the problem, just set to Serializable the isolation mode in HSQL (of course with a performance decrease).

Answer (score 0):

HSQL is an in-memory database, that probably has something to do with it.  Are both your client in different JVMs?  Probably not the best database for your needs.

Comment: True, but HSQL also allows remote connections over TCP.  The two clients are connecting from separate JVMs.  I chose HSQL so that I could process SQL on an in-memory DB.