# user lacks privilege or object not found: Object

Tags: maven, exception, intellij-idea, spring-batch, jdbctemplate

I was following the following basic spring batch tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ .

- I am using IntelliJ 14 and created a Spring-Batch project
- I am using Mavin. And I have pom.xml file.
- I haven't created any file except under src/main/resources/sample-data.csv.
- I didn't create any DB or JDBCTemplate since I assume it is not needed since the tutorial  uses in Memory DB.
- Mvn clean install works fine even though the Application.java shows me **"Couldn't autowire. No beans of jdbcTempalte type can be found"**
  @Autowired
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
- Spring-config has the following

> ```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
> ```
>
> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

- I am getting an error when I try to do `mvn spring-boot:run`

  The cause by shows `Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PEOPLE`

  What am I missing? I appreciate your help.

Comment: You sure your DB user has the permission to query?  You sure that the table exists?

Comment: @Makoto I haven't created any DB. The tutorial mentions "this example uses a memory-based database (provided by @EnableBatchProcessing), meaning that when it’s done, the data is gone."

Comment: But [**are you sure the table exists?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233037/org-hsqldb-hsqlexception-user-lacks-privilege-or-object-not-found-databasechan)

Comment: Where does it exist? you mean when it is created on the fly or in the csv file? I am a bit confused. And the log file didn't mention anything about that. Where do I check wether the table existed or not?

Comment: This is what I have in the csv file (each full name on a different line ) Jill, Doe
Joe ,Doe
Justin, Doe
Jane, Doe
John,Doe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put [schema initialisation](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing/blob/master/initial/src/main/resources/schema-all.sql) in your `src/main/resources`. Spring batch automatically runs `schema-@@platform@@.sql` during startup and `-all` tells it to be for all platforms as noted in `readme.adoc` on github:

> Next, you write a SQL script to create a table to store the data.
>
> src/main/resources/schema-all.sql
>
> link:initial/src/main/resources/schema-all.sql
>
> **Note:** Spring Boot runs
> schema-@@platform@@.sql automatically during startup. -all is the
> default for all platforms.

Comment: Thank you @Nenad. I'll give it a shot. They haven't mentioned anything on the tutorial and I assumed Spring does some of the magic behind :(

Comment: Yeah I was curious looking at tutorial how you get schema build so I went to github and realise they explain only there in readme, not on spring tutorial page. Spring boot does lot of magic but it cannot create schema for you :-)

Comment: True that. I was also digging the log file to see where the schema was created and didn't know about the github code they have. I hope this will work out. Let me play with it and I'll choose this as an answer if it works out so that you can get some points .. haha.. Thanks bro.

Comment: Now build went fine and the process was started. But I still don't see the output from run() method in Application class. This is the out put http://paste.ofcode.org/BQQzt5wGkV9ykMXTcGzmfD

Comment: Now that is probably whole another problem, try adding some more logging to writer, also to `Application` class but at least we solved db problem.

Comment: Still there is a problem. Because it's printing out the statement in the PersonItemProcessor which doesn't involve any DB connection. However, not the read write processor in Batch Configuration

Comment: You can do couple of things so we know what is happening: 1. Add `System.out` in `Àpplication` and `Writter` so we know what is happening and attach log (just add entering writer, entering aplication), place your code somewhere so I can see it since now I can only trust it is same as spring doc and check logged statements on hsql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192815/logging-sql-expressions-from-within-hsqldb

Comment: You can get the schema-all file for this tutorial from here: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing/find/master

(I faced same problem)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a Spring Batch without database configuration then you can use

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
```

More details can be found on thread [Spring-Batch without persisting metadata to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077549/spring-batch-without-persisting-metadata-to-database)